# Reasons for failing Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS install on older macbook?

Tags: boot, macbook

To start with, I have very limited experience inside a terminal. But here I am, with a Macbook Pro A1398 EMC 2881 which I've tried to install Ubuntu 20.04 on. I boot from live USB, then go through the installation process without any snags, but when I start the computer grub does not show up, just a blank backlit screen, not even a cursor. Holding alt and selecting the one EFI device that's available renders the same result. I am not sure what to do, any thoughts on what this could be are appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Linux 20.03"?

Comment: Ubuntu - sorry, been a long day

Comment: There's no "Ubuntu 20.03" either...

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Comment: Thanks. Now it makes some sense.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server? 20.04 LTS Desktop?  Which ISO or version?  (20.04? 20.04.1? 20.04.2? .. etc).  Did you verify the ISO as being valid before writing to media? or more importantly the write to your media?  (the write to ISO I find fails as USB-media is cheap/consumable - why verification is so important esp. if you have issues; how ISO written to media also matters as failure to boot may indicate a faulty write of ISO to media that is software version issue too).  Did you write in according with Ubuntu documentation?

Comment: Is it possible to get a "Recovery console" (google it), if yes: investigate system logs ( `$ dmesg | less` for starters)

Comment: `ls -ltr /var/log/` and `ls -lSr /var/log/` - lists and sorts the log files based on time and size, making the last and largest be at the end; these might be the most interesting ones.

Comment: So I realized there is now 22.04 LTS, so I downloaded it and mounted it onto a 16gb usb Iinstead of my old 8 gb) per instructions. When booting the live usb, I am prompted: "Unsupported SPROM revision: 11" and "No SPROM available". After a minute it booted and I was able to install it over the old installation, which it did in fact recognize in the installation menu and asked if I wanted to install over it. Now when I boot, I get /dev/sda2 recovering blocks, /dev/sd2 clean: xxx files xxx blocks for a few seconds and it changes to a blank screen, with no method of interaction, not even a cursor

Comment: Update: There are no error logs, logs show that the system boots just fine and everything is where it should be. But when I'm in recovery mode the screen is covered in scattered red pixels, I think the macbook graphics system may not be supported in the default list of graphics drivers in ubuntu, so the system will boot but will not display anything, and it seems to go unnoticed by the machine. I've seen people use 'nomodeset' to make the kernel use the basic kernel graphics on startup until x driver becomes available, but I am not sure the right way to go about that.